# C++ Build success, but run failed

Tags: c++

I am new c++ so forgive me to be asking this question. I created a project and run it the first time, it is successful. But when i start another project and i added 4 classes to it (you can see from the tabs) and the **main.cpp** is unable to run. I am confused as the codes are exactly the same in both projects.

Run Successful:
[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ismrO.png)

Build Successful but run failed:
[Run Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xgPk.png)

What are the solutions to solve this problem?

Do i have to post codes of all my classes? (there are 8 files)

**student.h:**

```
  #ifndef CLSSTUDENT_H
    #define CLSSTUDENT_H
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class clsStudent {

    protected:
        string name;
        string student_no;
        string program;

    public:
        clsStudent(string n, string sn,string prog );
        virtual void displayStudentDetails();



};
```

**student.cpp**

```
#include "TutorialClass.h"

void TutorialClass::addStudent(clsStudent std)
{

    _students.push_back(std);


}

int TutorialClass::getStudentCount()
{

    return _students.size();


}

void TutorialClass::display()
{


}
#endif /* CLSSTUDENT_H */
```

I open up a new project and added only this class. It is unable to run as well. What is the problem in the codes?

Comment: No, not all classes, only a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your program only fails to run when it's compiled with other files. My bet is that in these files you've got buggy code that is running *before* `main()` gets to run.

This can happen in cases like this:

```
int f() {
    throw; // bam! Uncaught exception;
}

int x = f(); // this runs before main()
```

Or this:

```
class C {
    C() {
        cout << "This runs before main() too!" << endl;
    }
};

C my_c; // calls constructor
```

In both cases: code was executed before `main()`. You want this because you want your global variables to be initialized before running `main()`. If this initialization code manages to crash the program via a segfault or an `exit()` call or throwing some exception which isn't caught? You've got a crashed program before it ever even gets the chance to run.